# Tox conditions to create a lib64 symlink

Tags: python, python-2.7, tox, pyenv

I have two virtual environments, both have the same version of tox (3.13.2) and the same python (2.7.5). Using the same tox.ini file, I get two different behaviours: in one case, there is a lib64 symlink, not in the other.

What causes tox to create it?

Tox.ini reads:

## Set up the run time environment

```
[tox]
envlist = env
minversion = 1.7.0
toxworkdir = {toxinidir}/virtenv
skipsdist = True

[testenv:rprs-env]
setenv=
    VIRTUAL_ENV = {envdir}
    PIP_USE_WHEEL= true
    PIP_NO_INDEX = true
deps = -r{toxinidir}/tox/requirements-pinned.txt
install_command = pip install --pre --find-links={toxinidir}/tox/wheelhouse {packages}
```

And command lines show:

```
test-devtree-Sxi7_C_t(feature/DTD-12|+4); ~/.virtualenvs/test_rprs_bootstrap/bin/tox -c tox.ini -r
env recreate: /home/usr/repos/test-devtree/Run/virtenv/env
env installdeps: -r/home/usr/repos/test-devtree/Run/tox/requirements-pinned.txt
env installed: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support,backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5,blosc==1.2.4,click==6.7,click-help-colors==0.4,colored-traceback==0.3.0,coloredlogs==10.0,cycler==0.10.0,Cython==0.24.1,docopt==0.6.2,enum==0.4.6,enum34==1.1.6,funcsigs==1.0.2,future==0.16.0,h5py==2.5.0,h5pyViewer==0.0.1.3,hickle==1.3.0,humanfriendly==4.16.1,humanize==0.5.1,kiwisolver==1.0.1,matplotlib==2.2.3,mock==1.0.0,monotonic==1.5,MySQL-python==1.2.3,nose==1.3.7,numexpr==2.6.8,numpy==1.15.1,pandas==0.23.4,pbr==1.10.0,py==1.4.30,Pygments==2.0.2,pyparsing==2.1.10,python-cjson==1.0.5,python-dateutil==2.7.3,pytz==2016.7,scipy==1.1.0,six==1.11.0,SQLAlchemy==0.9.7,subprocess32==3.2.7,sympy==0.7.6,tables==3.4.4,tox==1.7.0,Twisted==11.0.0,ujson==1.33,virtualenv==1.11.4,xlwt==1.0.0,zope.interface==4.1.1
env run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='1275167437'
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
  env: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
test-devtree-Sxi7_C_t(feature/DTD-12|+4); ls -l virtenv/env/
total 4.0K
4.0K drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr 4.0K Sep  2 12:25 bin/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr   22 Sep  2 12:25 include/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 3 usr usr   22 Sep  2 12:25 lib/
   0 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 usr usr    3 Sep  2 12:25 lib64 -> lib/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr   81 Sep  2 12:25 log/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 3 usr usr   17 Sep  2 12:25 man/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 3 usr usr   16 Sep  2 12:25 share/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr    6 Sep  2 12:25 tmp/
test-devtree-Sxi7_C_t(feature/DTD-12|+4); tox -c tox.ini -r 
env recreate: /home/usr/repos/test-devtree/Run/virtenv/env
env installdeps: -r/home/usr/repos/test-devtree/Run/tox/requirements-pinned.txt
env installed: DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support,backports.functools-lru-cache==1.5,blosc==1.2.4,click==6.7,click-help-colors==0.4,colored-traceback==0.3.0,coloredlogs==10.0,cycler==0.10.0,Cython==0.24.1,docopt==0.6.2,enum==0.4.6,enum34==1.1.6,funcsigs==1.0.2,future==0.16.0,h5py==2.5.0,h5pyViewer==0.0.1.3,hickle==1.3.0,humanfriendly==4.16.1,humanize==0.5.1,kiwisolver==1.0.1,matplotlib==2.2.3,mock==1.0.0,monotonic==1.5,MySQL-python==1.2.3,nose==1.3.7,numexpr==2.6.8,numpy==1.15.1,pandas==0.23.4,pbr==1.10.0,py==1.4.30,Pygments==2.0.2,pyparsing==2.1.10,python-cjson==1.0.5,python-dateutil==2.7.3,pytz==2016.7,scipy==1.1.0,six==1.11.0,SQLAlchemy==0.9.7,subprocess32==3.2.7,sympy==0.7.6,tables==3.4.4,tox==1.7.0,Twisted==11.0.0,ujson==1.33,virtualenv==1.11.4,xlwt==1.0.0,zope.interface==4.1.1
env run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='3823901851'
__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ summary __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
  env: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
test-devtree-Sxi7_C_t(feature/DTD-12|+4); ls -l virtenv/env/
total 4.0K
4.0K drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr 4.0K Sep  2 12:26 bin/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr   22 Sep  2 12:25 include/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 3 usr usr   22 Sep  2 12:25 lib/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr   81 Sep  2 12:26 log/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 3 usr usr   17 Sep  2 12:25 man/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 3 usr usr   16 Sep  2 12:26 share/
   0 drwxrwxr-x. 2 usr usr    6 Sep  2 12:26 tmp/
test-devtree-Sxi7_C_t(feature/DTD-12|+4); tox --version    
3.13.2 imported from /home/usr/.virtualenvs/test-devtree-Sxi7_C_t/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.pyc
test-devtree-Sxi7_C_t(feature/DTD-12|+4); ~/.virtualenvs/test_rprs_bootstrap/bin/tox --version    
3.13.2 imported from /home/usr/.virtualenvs/test_rprs_bootstrap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tox/__init__.pyc
```

Answer (score 0):

***☠ pyenv was the culprit!***

If you use a locally installed version, then install tox, then use that tox then no `lib64` symlink will be created. However, if you specify `pyenv local  system` as the Python version you want to use, then create your pipenv virtual environment with

```
pipenv install --ignore-pipfile --python=/usr/bin/python
```

You should get tox to create a `lib64` symlink.

A much better solution (with 20/20 hindsight) is not to rely on `lib64` for Python…